# Access Instagram friends media feed (home timeline)?

Tags: instagram

Is there a way to retrieve the "Home Timeline" (i.e.: a feed with all latest photos by people the authenticated user is following) using the Instagram API?

I couldn't find this method in [the docs](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is called the ["Self feed" (users/self/feed)](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_feed)

Comment: No way to get this in xml is there?

Comment: Yeah, it does not seem this is supported anymore.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Instagram API Changelog](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/), the Self-feed Endpoint was deprecated in November 2015.

The only way that worked until recently was to fetch the followed users list and read their feeds one by one. Unfortunately, new applications can only request Basic permission now since October 2017, which basically means that there is no way to read user's own feed.